# Haskell TypeApplication-like way of explicitly picking an implementation of an interface

Tags: interface, idris, implements

I'm using Idris 2 v0.3. I can't see why the compiler can't find an implementation for `Gaussian` of `Distribution` in

```
interface Distribution dist where
  mean : dist -> Double

data Gaussian : Type where
  MkGaussian : Double -> Gaussian

Distribution Gaussian where
    mean (MkGaussian mean') = mean'

KnowledgeBased : Distribution d => (d : Type) -> Type

ei : KnowledgeBased Gaussian
```

I'm getting error

```
"src/Foo.idr" 12L, 459C written
Error: While processing type of ei. Can't find an implementation for Distribution ?d.

.../src/Foo.idr:12:6--12:29
    |
 12 | ei : KnowledgeBased Gaussian
    |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scoping is wrong; in `Distribution d => (d : Type) -> Type`, the `Distribution d` part implicitly binds `d`, and then it is shadowed by `d : Type`.

Instead what you want is:

```
KnowledgeBased : (d : Type) -> Distribution d => Type
```

Here, the first `d : Type` binds `d` with a Pi; it parses as `(d : Type) -> (Distribution d => Type)`. So the `d` in `Distribution d` is now bound, and no automatic implicit binding is done.

However, this is not idiomatic Idris. Instead, you should use the `Distribution d`-bound implicit parameter and not worry about tricks to make it explicit:

```
KnowledgeBased : Distribution d => Type

ei : KnowledgeBased {d = Gaussian}
```

Comment: I changed the title because I think it will help others find this question more easily -- a lot of people go to Idris with Haskell experience. I think the idiomatic version would be `Knowledgebased {d = Gaussian}`.