# Can't find implementation with constraint in signature

Tags: idris

I have an interface that depends on another interface, with some dependent types, and I can't get the compiler to constrain a type in a related function

```
import Data.Vect

interface Distribution (0 event : Nat) (dist : Nat -> Nat -> Type) where

data Gaussian : Nat -> Nat -> Type where

Distribution e Gaussian where

interface Distribution targets marginal =>
 Model (targets : Nat) (marginal : Nat -> Nat -> Type) model where
  marginalise : model -> Vect s Double -> marginal targets s

foo : m -> Model 1 Gaussian m => Vect s Double -> Nat
foo model x = let marginal = marginalise model x in ?rhs
```

I get

```
While processing right hand side of foo. Can't find an implementation for Model ?targets ?marginal m.

foo model x = let marginal = marginalise model x in ?rhs  
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How could this be?

If I use `marginalise {marginal=Gaussian} {targets=1} model x` it type checks, but I don't get why this isn't already determined by the type signature.

I don't think [this qu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67594194/5986907) I asked about the same area applies here

Comment: There's no fundep from `model` to `marginal` or `targets` in `Model`, and the type of `marginal`  in `foo` isn't constrained in any way (its type is `marginal targets s` for some choice of `marginal`, `targets` and `s`), so it has no reason to pick any particular choice of `targets` and `marginal` just because you happen to have one particular instance for one particular choice in scope.

Comment: @Cactus ok thanks. It seems constraints in idris work quite differently to how they do in python/scala. You talk of "having an instance in scope" rather than a constraint, too, as though `Model 1 Gaussian m =>` isn't really a constraint. Have I got that right? If so, how do I make such a constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started writing this as a comment and realized halfway through that it might work as a full-blown answer.

`Model 1 Gaussan m` means that you have an implementation of the `Model` interface with `targets = 1`, `marginal = Gaussian` and `model = m`. Then, the let-binding of `marginal` requires `Model a b m`, i.e. an implementation of `Model` where `targets = a` , `marginal = b` and `model = m`. But there is no requirement that `a = 1` and `b = Gaussian`!

My guess is that once you read up on [determining parameters](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/interfaces.html#determining-parameters), you will discover that you want something like:

```
interface Distribution targets marginal =>
 Model (targets : Nat) (marginal : Nat -> Nat -> Type) model | model where
```

Comment: when you say "the binding of `marginal`", which line do mean on? I've used `marginal` in a number of places

Comment: @joel: I mean the let-binding

Comment: this fixes my problem, thank you! I'm not yet clear on why, but I'll read more

Comment: @joel maybe try https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies ?